# XHRHTTPRequest response cannot be equal to normal string

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to compare a success string with `xhr.responseText` but it is not working, I have no idea why.

```
if (xhr.responseText == "success")
{
    alert("Yay");
}
```

What could be the reason? I tried to alert the responseTest and it has exactly same value, "success" in it.

Comment: Are you doing that when `xhr.readyState == 4`?

Comment: yeah, once I get ready state I check the responseText and compare wether my php script responded with success or failure.

Comment: Keep in mind that your comparison will be case sensitive and not forgiving of leading/trailing white space. Make sure that there is no white space outside the `<?php ?>` tags in your PHP script.

Comment: @DaveRandom I tried trimming the response text and that worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet there is something else there. It is better to use console.log instead of alert. Modern day browsers have a console built in.

```
alert(escape(xhr.responseText));
```

This will show you other characters that are not visible in the alert.

Comment: Apperently the cause was the response text was having some whitespace, My php script was sending pure string with no whitespace in head or tail end but some how once I received the responseText it contained whitespace so I just trimmed the response and then compared it with "success" string and that worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are developer, i suposed that you are working on firefox with firebug, try to print the xhr.response object in order to debug your script with the following sentence:
     console.log(xhr.responseText);